# GWT - LatLonPoint Constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, openstreetmap

Using GWT I'm trying to display a portlet with an OpenStreetMap map in my web application using this lines:

```
    MapPanel osm = new OpenStreetMap();
    latlon=new LatLonPoint(10.35,35.15);
    osm.setCenterAndZoom(latlon, 10);
    osm.setWidth(100);
    osm.setHeight(100);
```

After that, I insert the `MapPanel` in a portlet to display it.
When I create the web application, the application works (I can display the other portlets), but I can't display the portlet that contains my map.
This is what Eclipse says:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.gwtext.client.widgets.map.LatLonPoint::create(DD)([double: 10.35, double: 35.15]): $wnd.LatLonPoint is not a constructor
```

I've successfully imported the com.gwtext.client.widgets.map.LatLonPoint library, like Eclipse suggested to me.

What else must I do?

Comment: Did you accidentally create a variable named `LatLonPoint` before?

Comment: No, I didn't. There isn't any variable named 'LatLonPoint', before

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm working on Ubuntu, with Firefox 24.3.0 (later versions do not support GWT).